# tsoa @Route decorator with variable dosen't works in express app

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, tsoa

I can't find any information wh `@Route` decorator doesn't work with a variable instead of `"string"`.

A swagger definition generated with code below is wrong.

```js
export const PATH_GROUP = "/my-path";

export enum PATHS {
  GetButtons = "/",
}

@Route(PATH_GROUP)
export class ButtonsController {
  @Get(PATH_GROUP.GetButtons)
  @Tags("Buttons")
  public static async getButtons(): Promise<ButtonViewModel[]> {
    const buttons = await buttonsService.getAllButtons();

    return buttons.map(button => button.toAddToViewModel());
  }
}
```

When I generate a new swagger definition it looks like:
[image: buttons-swagger-section]

If I use strings instead of variable/enum everything works correctly.

```js
@Route("/my-path")
export class ButtonsController {
  @Get("/")
  @Tags("Buttons")
  public static async getButtons(): Promise<ButtonViewModel[]> {
    const buttons = await buttonsService.getAllButtons();

    return buttons.map(button => button.toAddToViewModel());
  }
}
```

Is there any information about not using variables in tsoa decorators?

Comment: Any updates on this? Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I think swagger gets only decorators to generate schema and don't check other code so if we declare a path in another variable swagger won't see it. But it is only my guess.